# Javascript - loop thro array and sort the objects based on the key value inside

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, object

I have a simple array which i get via json where each object has a `position` key with a certain value. I would like to reorder them (change their index) based on the value of that key inside.

Here is what i have so far: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gLe371r2/)

The code:

```
var mess = [
    a = {
    lorem: "ipsum",
    position: 3
  },
  b = {
    lorem: "ipsum",
    position: 2
  },
  c = {
    lorem: "ipsum",
    position: 4
  },
  d = {
    lorem: "ipsum",
    position: 1
  }
]

var order = [];

for (i = 0; i < mess.length; i++) {
    order.splice(mess[i].position - 1, 0, mess[i]);
}
```

The issue with the current loop is that only the first and last object get arranged properly (1, 4) within `order` array.

Comment: please add data and the code, you tried to the question. please have a look here, too: [mcve]

Comment: Fiddle is posted.

Comment: What all of these global `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` variables for?

Comment: Just for a quick demo in fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.sort` method:

```js
let mess = [
 {lorem: "ipsum",position: 3},
 {lorem: "ipsum",position: 2},
 {lorem: "ipsum",position: 4},
 {lorem: "ipsum",position: 1}
];

// 
console.log(mess.sort((a, b) => a.position - b.position))
```

Comment: Yep, forgot about sort, thanks!

Comment: Or `mess.sort(function(a, b) { return a.position - b.position })` if you run in an enviroment that doesn't have [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: @Ben, you miss `return` statement

Comment: @vp_arth, saw that after posting. Fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the position as index for the new array.

```js
var mess = [{ lorem: "ipsum", position: 3 }, { lorem: "ipsum", position: 2 }, { lorem: "ipsum", position: 4 }, { lorem: "ipsum", position: 1 }],
    order = [],
    i;

for (i = 0; i < mess.length; i++) {
    order[mess[i].position - 1] = mess[i];
}

console.log(order);
```

Or you could iterate from the end to start, this works for not continuing positions as well.

```js
var mess = [{ lorem: "ipsum", position: 3 }, { lorem: "ipsum", position: 2 }, { lorem: "ipsum", position: 4 }, { lorem: "ipsum", position: 1 }],
    order = [],
    i = mess.length;

while (i--) {
    order.splice(mess[i].position - 1, 0, mess[i]);
}

console.log(order);
```

Comment: Thanks Nina, works great!

Answer (score 1):

try sort:

```
order = mess.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.position - b.position;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Maria, forgot about sort - voted up!